# Convert datetime.time column in pandas to total minutes

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, series, timedelta

I have a `datetime.time` Series in Pandas and I want to convert it to an int series which contains the `total minutes`.
Anyway I could do that?

I have tried converting it to `timedelta` using

```py
train['time_order'] = pd.to_timedelta(train['time_order']).dt.total_seconds()
train['time_order'] = train['time_order']%60
```

but I get the error

`Invalid type for timedelta scalar: <class 'datetime.time'>`
since the format of the column is in `datetime.time`

Comment: Answer was closed incorrect, so reopened.

Answer (score 1):

Convert column to strings first:

```
train['time_order'] = pd.to_timedelta(train['time_order'].astype(str)).dt.total_seconds()%60
```